# How to start music playback in Activity from thread?

Tags: android, multithreading, android-mediaplayer

I am unable to start MediaPlayer in Activity from a thread.
I have sounds loaded in my Android activity, called Snakes, and played from a custom View class...

```
Activity Snakes()...
    void playSound(int i){
        if (sounds != null){
            sounds.play(sound_questions[i], 1.0f, 1.0f, 0, 0, 1.0f);
        }
    }


CustomView()...
    ((Snakes)getContext()).playSound();
```

This works.

I have music playback via MediaPlayer in my Activity class. To delay start, I want to use mediaPlayer.Start() called from the game control thread. I have approached this the same as the sound playback, and placed this into a simple method in my Activity class

```
    void startMusic(){
    mediaPlayer.start();
}
```

However, I cannot call this method from the thread.

How should I start MediaPlayer in the activity from a thread?

Comment: Use a Handler to send a message from thread to the activity telling it to start MediaPlayer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put a message handler in your activity.

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity {

    // Handler message constants
    public static final int PLAY_SOUND = 0;
    public static final int SOME_OTHER_MESSAGE = 1;
    ...

    private final MainHandler mMainHandler = new MainHandler(this);

    // Handler
    private static class MainHandler extends Handler {

        // Using a WeakReference is recommended to avoid memory leaks
        private final WeakReference<MainActivity> mActivity;
        public MainHandler(MainActivity activity) {
            mActivity = new WeakReference<MainActivity>(activity);
        }

        // The message handler
        @Override
        public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
            MainActivity activity = mActivity.get();
            if (activity != null) {
                final int index;
                switch (msg.what) {
                case PLAY_SOUND:
                    activity.playMySound();
                    break;
                case SOME_OTHER_MESSAGE:
                    ...
                    break;
                ...
                }   
            }           
        }
    };

    private void playMySound() {
    ...
    }
}
```

Get a reference to the handler in your thread and use it to send messages to the activity.

```
public class MyThread extends Thread {

    private Handler mParentHandler;

    // Constructor
    private MyThread(Handler parentHandler) {
        mParentHandler = parentHandler;
    }

    ...
    // When you want to start playback
    Message messageToMain = Message.obtain();
    messageToMain.what = MainActivity.PLAY_SOUND;
    mParentHandler.sendMessage(messageToMain);
    ...
}
```

Alternatively, if passing the main message handler to the thread through it's constructor is not suitable for your situation, you can create a static method in your thread to pass it the handler at a class level.

```
public class MyThread extends Thread {

    // make mHandler static so it can be defined at a class level.
    private static Handler mHandler;

    // Constructor
    private MyThread(...) {
        // no need to pass Handler in constructor now
    }

    // static method for setting mHandler
    public static void setHandler(Handler suppliedHandler) {
        mHandler = suppliedHandler;
    }

    ...
    // When you want to start playback
    Message messageToMain = Message.obtain();
    messageToMain.what = MainActivity.PLAY_SOUND;
    mHandler.sendMessage(messageToMain);
    ...
}
```

Then make sure you set the handler for the thread to use before any instances of the thread are created (for example do it in the onCreate() of the activity).

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity {

    // Handler message constants
    public static final int PLAY_SOUND = 0;
    public static final int SOME_OTHER_MESSAGE = 1;
    ...

    private final MainHandler mMainHandler = new MainHandler(this);

    // Handler
    private static class MainHandler extends Handler {

        // Using a WeakReference is recommended to avoid memory leaks
        private final WeakReference<MainActivity> mActivity;
        public MainHandler(MainActivity activity) {
            mActivity = new WeakReference<MainActivity>(activity);
        }

        // The message handler
        @Override
        public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
            MainActivity activity = mActivity.get();
            if (activity != null) {
                final int index;
                switch (msg.what) {
                case PLAY_SOUND:
                    activity.playMySound();
                    break;
                case SOME_OTHER_MESSAGE:
                    ...
                    break;
                ...
                }   
            }           
        }
    };

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        ...
        MyThread.setHandler(mMainHandler);
        // setting this at a class level means all future instances of MyThread
        // will have their mHandler set to mMainHandler
        ...
    }

    private void playMySound() {
    ...
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. How do I get a reference to the Handler though? My thread is called from my custom view and not the Activity, so my thread constructor is called... runThread = new SnakeThread(getHolder(), this, <handler?>);

Comment: You can modify this same approach. Put the handler in your custom view instead of in the Activity. Then define an interface in your custom view, so you can set a listener to it in your main activity. I've recently done something similar myself.

Comment: Actually, instead of passing the handler through the constructor of the thread, you could define a static setHandler method in your thread class. Then you'd be able to set the handler for your thread to use at a class level, before you create any instances of your thread class(In other words, you'd be able to use`MyThread.setHandler(mMainHandler)` from in your activities onCreate()).

Comment: That's the most thorough, comprehensive answer I've ever seen on StackOverflow! Thanks. :D